# Can two apps read data from the same BLE sensor in Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Can two independent apps (on the same phone)  read the data from the same BLE sensor?

Case in point: Can I develop an app that gets the HR from a BT HR sensor while another app is already connected to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can only have one active connection at the same time. For two handsets to read from one heart rate monitor you would have to connect one, do a read, disconnect, connect the other, do a read.

A possible workaround is if you include the heartrate in the advertisement packet. This way you don't even have to be connected at all.

Comment: That's for replying! It's the same phone , but two different apps.

Comment: It's still not possible to do this across apps. If you're trying to "steal" the connection from another app you could try using `BluetoothAdapter.disable()` then `BluetoothAdapter.enable()`, which will kill all connections, then your app could quickly connect. Resetting the Bluetooth stack like this is not trivial though, especially since Marshmallow, so I would highly encourage you to check out [SweetBlue](https://github.com/iDevicesInc/SweetBlue), specifically [BleManager.reset()](http://idevicesinc.com/sweetblue/docs/api/com/idevicesinc/sweetblue/BleManager.html#reset--).